# WordPress : Redirect a form validation & submit

Tags: forms, wordpress, redirect, submit

What would be the best way to redirect a form after validation & submit? The form isn't a plugin, it's part of a theme.

a) This is the form action code:

```
<form action="" id="pro_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

b) Here's the validation string:

```
<input  type="submit" onclick="return validation()" value="Submit"  >
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Peter

Comment: How do you submit the form? Is it regular form submit or using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is want you are asking for, but in my opinion the best way is using javascript, like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="NewLocation";</script>';
```

Place this code after the form returns from validation.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

The above javascript does redirect to another URL, but what I need is the redirection to happen after the form has been submitted.

Comment: That redirection should be set in the action field of the form: `action="WhereFormIsChecked"`.

Comment: Just in case, there is an action following the submission: `onclick="return validation()"` which has priority over any other.